# Part of the footer jumps up on another component, but only when the page loads in react

Tags: css, reactjs

I code this part some time ago, and after working in other pages I came back to notice this weird behavior.

I tried to change the css to force both component footer and main fill the width, it didn't work also tried to wrap them in divs the issue still remains

Please check this screenshot showing the issue:

[issueReact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyUxS.gif)

here you can see the code, but the issue does not reproduce
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-bhabha-ns7374?file=/src/main.css

home.tsx

```
import Footer from "../components/Footer/Footer";
import Menu from "../components/Menu/Menu";
import logoFull from "../assets/RG-Logo-verde.svg";
import "../main.css";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="box">
        <div className="row header">
          <Menu selected="home" />
        </div>

        <main className="row content flex-column">
          <div className="homeImage">
            <img src={logoFull} alt="Home Image" />
          </div>
          <div className="row content flex-column">
            <h1 className="bold large-font text-center">
              Lorem ipsum dolor
            </h1>
            <p className="mediun-size">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          </div>
          <div className="presentation">
            <h2 className="bold">Presentaction</h2>
            <p className="mediun-size">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
              Suspendisse imperdiet arcu eget blandit eleifend. Proin congue
              erat dui, quis elementum nisl tempor quis. Praesent fringilla
              massa at auctor consequat. Phasellus a fermentum nibh. Praesent
              tincidunt est justo, ac vestibulum quam feugiat imperdiet. Quisque
              facilisis arcu nec metus fermentum, nec vulputate nunc feugiat.
              Praesent placerat diam ullamcorper nisl congue, ut elementum augue
              tempor. Pellentesque id pharetra lorem, eu venenatis urna. Etiam
              quam lorem, malesuada quis volutpat vel, hendrerit vel nisi. Proin
              pretium aliquam elit.
            </p>
          </div>
        </main>

        <footer className="row footer">
          <Footer />
        </footer>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

footer.tsx

```
import "./Footer.css";

export default function Footer() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="footer-container">
        <div className="contact-footer">
          <p>Contacto: (+591) 1234567</p>
        </div>
        <div className="email-footer">
          <p>E-mail: fabiolaalba1919@gmail.com</p>
        </div>
        <div className="rights-footer">
          <p>Derechos reservados - 2023</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

footer.css

```
.footer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.email-footer {
  margin: 5px auto;
}

.contact-footer,
.rights-footer {
  margin: 5px 40px;
}
```

main.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: AileronRegular;
  src: url("./assets/font/Aileron-Regular.otf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Aileronbold;
  src: url("./assets/font/Aileron-Bold.otf");
}

* {
  font-family: AileronRegular;
}
:root {
  --color-one: #70ae6e;
  --color-two: #ff9b71;
  --bg-gradiant: url("./assets/radiant-gradient1.svg");
  --bg-rose: url("./assets/rose-petals1.svg");
}

body {
  background-image: var(--bg-rose);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

html,
body,
#root {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.box .row.content .presentation {
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 20px auto 40px auto;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}

footer {
  background-color: var(--color-one);
  margin-top: auto;
}

a:hover {
  color: var(--color-one);
}

.homeImage img {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

main {
  text-align: center;
}
main,
footer,
header {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  --bs-gutter-x: 0rem !important;
}

.mediun-font {
  font-size: x-large;
}

.large-font {
  font-size: xxx-large;
}

.bold {
  font-family: Aileronbold;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2rem;
  margin: 5rem 0;
}

.centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.percented {
  width: 60% !important;
}

.box2-serv {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: left;
}
.box3-serv {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: left;
}

.black-link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card-container {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.box-us {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: left;
}

.pad-bot-3 {
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

.cont-brand {
}
```

Comment: Please add a code snippet, codesandbox or a stackblitz so that it is easier to repro the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the SVG not being able to completely render. I have changed it and it's working fine now, all though I still don't know how to fix it using the previous SVG, if you find yourself with this issue changing the SVG is a work around to the problem.